# Center floating divs inside of absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have this set of html and css. What I want is to have to have the small gadgets blocks float left but to centered inside of the absolute positioned gadget-wrapper.

So, the gadget wrapper is absolute positioned to the bottom of a page. It holds x number of gadgets that floats left inside of the wrapper.

All these gadget should be centered inside the wrapper - is this possible and how ...? This is really killing me ....

**HTML**

```
<div id="gadget-wrapper">
    <div class="gadget">
        <h2>1</h2>
        <div class="value-holder critical">not set</div>
        <div class="value-holder non-critical">not set</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gadget">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <div class="value-holder critical">not set</div>
        <div class="value-holder non-critical">not set</div>
    </div>
    <div class="gadget">
        <h2>3</h2>
        <div class="value-holder critical">not set</div>
        <div class="value-holder non-critical">not set</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#gadget-wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid green;
}

.gadget h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.gadget {
    min-width: 120px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #383838;
    opacity: 0.75;
    float: left;
    border: 4px solid #000;
}

.value-holder.critical.active {
    color: #FF0000;
}

.value-holder.non-critical.active {
    color: #FFFF00;
}

.value-holder {
    font-size: 28px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried making the `gadget` elements inline and aligning them to the center with text-align?

```
#gadget-wrapper {
    ...
    text-align: center;
}

.gadget {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
}
```

This might work, I'm just not sure how the block level elements inside will behave (I'm unable to test this right now). You can also try `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE5.5, 6 or 7 according to IETester. They just stack on top of each other, works perfectly in everything else though.

Comment: This just helped me..thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 3):

`display: inline-block;` works with the first answer. make sure you removed `float: left;`